# Is is possible to have http service using cxf without tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, cxf

I am writing a server which is used to provide service using http protocol. (The server is not designed to be accessed from broswer, it's used to provide data for iphone client) I know cxf library has good support for this. Is it possible to do this without tomcat.
If possible, a sample project or sample config file would be great.

(I think the question could also be understood as do we have to use the web container like tomcat for http protocal)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use tomcat.   CXF has an HTTP transport that uses an embedded Jetty instance to provide HTTP server support for the case where you don't use Tomcat or other servlet engine.   Almost all of the sample applications that CXF ships in the samples directory use this when you use the -Pserver maven profile.